# how show file upload progress in google drive api?

Tags: javascript, php, google-drive-api

how to show file upload progress in google drive api?
is possible? (in php or javascript)

I use **google api php clinet library**

Comment: Have you googled for this? What have you tried? Did it not work?

Comment: I can't find anythings.I can upload and get id of uploaded file.i want see progress when file is uploading.

Comment: I think your looking for [malsup file upload](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload).

Comment: Upload from where? Your question says you use php client library which suggests you are connecting to Drive from a web server. So are you uploading from a Web server to drive? Then you ask about Javascript. Do you want to upload from a browser to Drive? Or are you uploading from a browser to your Web app?

Comment: I use remote upload file. i download file from url to my server then upload it to google drive.(chuk upload) why ask about javascript? for is possible use ajax to get information about upload progress from php script?